# getting a ValueError when i try to enter something which is not in the List even though i told the program what to do if this happens

Tags: python, list

```py
import sys
global x
global y

lolusrnm = []
lolpasswrd = []
def login_function():
    while True:
        global usrnm
        usrnm = str(input("please enter your username : "))
        if usrnm in lolusrnm:
            while True:
                global passwrd
                global chkusrnmindx
                global chkpasswrdindx
                passwrd = str(input("Please enter your password : "))
                chkusrnmindx = lolusrnm.index(usrnm)
                chkpasswrdindx = lolpasswrd.index(passwrd)
                if passwrd in lolpasswrd and chkpasswrdindx == chkusrnmindx:
                    print("uou are in ")
                    sys.exit()
                
                elif passwrd not in lolpasswrd:
                    print("password dont match try again")
                else:
                    global quot2
                    print("Wrong password, try again")
                    quot2 = str(input("do u want to continue "))
                    if quot2 == "Y":
                        continue
                    elif quot2 == "N":
                        
                        sys.exit()                  
        else:
            print("Username dosent match..")
def signup_function():
    while True:
        global x
        global y
        print("Enter your username")
        x = str(input())
        lolusrnm.append(x)
        y = str(input("Enter your password : " ))
        lolpasswrd.append(y)
        global sassy
        sassy = input("Do you want to (L)ogin? or continue to (S)ign up another account?")
        if sassy == "L":
            login_function()
        elif sassy == "S":
            continue
        
signup_function()
```

So, this is a simple program I made in python that stores a my username and password in list, and then when i want to login, it asks me the username and password. the problem here is when I run my code, It first asks for my username and password and puts it in the list. then when i login with the username i entered when i  sign up, and then enter a password which is NOT in the list, the code fails, and gives this error :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\chand\Desktop\PythonBrocode.py", line 52, in <module>       
    signup_function()
  File "c:\Users\chand\Desktop\PythonBrocode.py", line 48, in signup_function
    login_function()
  File "c:\Users\chand\Desktop\PythonBrocode.py", line 18, in login_function 
    chkpasswrdindx = lolpasswrd.index(passwrd)
ValueError: '(whatever password i enter which is not in the list)' is not in list
```

even though i told the computer what to do when a password that is not in the list is entered :

```py
elif passwrd not in lolpasswrd:
                    print("password dont match try again")
```

Im learning python and i am very new to coding. please help me, and sorry for my bad coding skills :(

Comment: `chkpasswrdindx = lolpasswrd.index(passwrd)` is called outside the test.

Comment: If you're learning Python, be aware that programmers try very, very hard to avoid `global`. I have used `global` in Python only once in over 20 years. `global` leads to inflexible and unmaintainable code. Functions get the data they need as parameters and give back values with `return`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are running list.index method before check is value inside list, like documentation said:

list.index(x[, start[, end]])
Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is equal to x. Raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

You need yo check is this value inside list before getting its index.